# How to loop data combine while function and if condition

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I want to know about while function.
I want to combine **while** function with **if** condition.
I need loop data in **if** condition.

Here is my code:

```js
var loop = function () {
   var x = 0;
   var y = 10;
   var z = 0;

   while (x > y) {
        var qty = 5;
        var price = 100;        
        
        if(qty > 5) {
         p = (qty * price) - 1;
        } else {
         p = (qty * price) + 1;
        }
        
        y = y + qty;
        z = z + p;
   }
   console.log("result " + y, z);
};

loop();
```

I have try to change it like this and working.

```js
//Remember to set your condition outside the loop!
var x = 0;
var y = 10;
var z = 0;

var loop = function () {
    while (x < y) {        
        
        var qty = 5;
        var price = 100;        
        
        if(qty > 5) {
         p = (qty * price) - 1;
        } else {
         p = (qty * price) + 1;
        }
        
        var result = x++ + p;        
        console.log("result " + result);
    }
};

loop();
```

But why the value different if i added new line.
var resulty = a++ + p 
var resultx = a++ + qty

Thank you

Comment: what is the issue ??

Comment: result is not follow in while function. what i want show the loop data in if condition

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with while condition. x should be less than y then loop the statement

`while (x < y) {`

Comment: when i change it like this x < y my browser not response (crash)

Comment: sorry i check that, seem ur question is little confusing..what you are trying to solve

Comment: I have change it and working now. But i am confuse why the value change when i add new line. My question edited. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

x is less than y and don't get into the loop as per your while condition. Try changing it

Comment: when i change it like this x < y my browser not response (crash)

Comment: there is no increment in x before loop ends. That’s why it is causing infinite loop

Answer (score -1):

This while loop doesn't execute because x initializes as 0 and will never be greater than y.

I imagine switching those values would at least get the while loop to execute.

However -- even then --- the qty never changes from 5 --- so the following if/else statement is rendered superflous (only the else ever executes).

Hope that helps --- feel free to add details to what exactly the x, y, z represent and what the function loop is trying to accomplish.

```js
var loop = function () {
   var x = 0;
   var y = 10;
   var z = 0;

   while (x > y) {
        var qty = 5;
        var price = 100;        
        
        if(qty > 5) {
         p = (qty * price) - 1;
        } else {
         p = (qty * price) + 1;
        }
        
        y = y + qty;
        z = z + p;
      
        console.log("n1 " + y);
        console.log("n2 " + z);
 
        console.log("n2 " + x);
        x++;
   }
   console.log("result " + x++);
};

loop();
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Hey --- I accidentally posted --- please note updated answer and I hope that clarifies my intention. New to StackOverflow.